# cloud9 installation on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, cloud9-ide

I have installed the cloud9 on my ubuntu server by following the instructions given in the following link.
https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/tree/master

when i start the cloud9 on my server through mindterm ssh, i got the message that it was running in the url [http://localhost:3131], but when i access the url i can't get any response in my browser, i could i locate the cloud9 response. how can i get the cloud9 response in my browser?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my last time installation of cloud9 ide on my ubuntu server, i left the requirements section of installing the cloud9 ide. When i had seen the requirements i forget to install the

```
libxml2-dev
```

package in my server. After installing the above package ,cloud ide is running in my server.

Answer (score 1):

you can open your firebug , and look the Console!
There are details about your request and response from the server!